# Fail to decode JSON because the model is Identifiable

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have a JSON like this

```
[
 {
   "name": "car",
   "color": "red"
 },
 {
   "name": "bike",
   "color": "blue"
 },
  ... etc
]
```

and I have this model to use during the decode

```
struct Element:Codable {
  var name:String?
  var color:String?
}
```

later in code I have a `ScrollView` like this

```
 ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, alignment: .center, spacing: 10, content: {
          ForEach(allElements) { element in
```

`allElements` is an array of `Element`.

because I am using `allElements` there, I have to make `Element` identifiable...

```
struct Element:Codable, Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()
  var name:String?
  var color:String?
}
```

Now it fails to decode the JSON, because the JSON does not have `id`.

I have tried to add

```
"id" : "",
```

to all elements on the JSON without success.

any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to tell the compiler that `id` is not part of the JSON. You can do so, by declaring a `CodingKey` compliant `enum` on your `Codable` type.

The synthetised `Codable` methods will only use the keys in the `CodingKey` compliant `enum` for decoding/encoding your type. So if you leave out `id` from the `enum` and only specify `name` and `color`, `Codable` won't try to look for an `id` key in the JSON.

```
struct Element: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name:String?
    var color:String?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case color
        case name
    }
}
```